# Rolling subsetting of a time series data frame based on index values (time points), not number of observations R

Tags: r, time-series, subset, rolling-computation

I have a data frame with one timescale and multiple time series. I would like to subset it in a dynamically rolling way with the width of the window set to e.g. 10 yrs. Because the time series is not equidistantly sampled the number of rows in the window will change as it rolls along the data frame.
The calculations should be done based on time values and not number of observations.

For example, in the following data.frame:

```
time    var1    var2
5262    -8.981  -0.011
5263.2  -8.993  -0.012
5264.4  -8.978  0.015
5265.6  -9.169  -0.191
5266.8  -8.897  0.272
5268    -9.024  -0.127
5269.2  -8.996  0.028
5270.46 -8.979  0.017
5271.84 -9.004  -0.025
5273.22 -9.01   -0.006
5274.6  -9.106  -0.096
5275.98 -8.971  0.135
5277.36 -8.996  -0.025
5278.74 -8.956  0.04
5280.12 -8.981  -0.025
5281.5  -8.982  -0.001
5282.88 -9.042  -0.06
5284.26 -9.091  -0.049
5285.64 -9.066  0.025
5287.02 -9.03   0.036
5288.4  -9.031  -0.001
5289.78 -9.028  0.003
5291.16 -9.164  -0.136
5294.72 -9.034  0.13
5297.3  -9.296  -0.262
5299.88 -9.097  0.199
5302.46 -8.995  0.102
5305.04 -9.084  -0.089
5307.62 -9.047  0.037
5310.2  -9.066  -0.019
5312.78 -9.07   -0.004
5315.36 -9  0.07
5317.94 -9.057  -0.057
5320.52 -9.219  -0.162
5323.1  -9.084  0.135
5325.68 -9.034  0.05
5328.26 -9.147  -0.113
5330.84 -9.169  -0.022
5333.42 -9.143  0.026
5336    -9.211  -0.068
5338.58 -9.061  0.15
5341.16 -9.1    -0.039
5343.74 -9.094  0.006
5346.32 -9.104  -0.01
5348.9  -9.089  0.015
5351.48 -9.127  -0.038
5354.06 -8.973  0.154
5356.64 -9.009  -0.036
5359.22 -8.966  0.043
5361.8  -8.996  -0.03
5364.38 -8.877  0.119
5366.96 -8.962  -0.085
5369.54 -8.902  0.06
5372.12 -8.915  -0.013
5374.7  -8.913  0.002
5377.28 -8.834  0.079
5379.86 -8.91   -0.076
5382.44 -8.742  0.168
5385.02 -8.877  -0.135
5387.6  -8.743  0.134
5390.18 -8.898  -0.155
5392.76 -8.77   0.128
5395.34 -8.97   -0.2
5397.92 -8.849  0.121
5400.5  -8.846  0.003
5403.08 -8.865  -0.019
5405.66 -8.865  0
5408.24 -8.876  -0.011
5410.82 -8.775  0.101
5413.4  -8.842  -0.067
5415.98 -8.821  0.021
5418.56 -8.85   -0.029
```

What I did before is subsetting the df but by referring to the rownumbers with the following code and performing a linear regression.

```
data.column=2
time.column=1
length=dim(data)[1] 
window=10
adj_r_sqr=matrix(0,nrow=length,length(window_vekt))
colnames(adj_r_sqr)=window


    for(i in 1:(length-window)){
        x=data[i:(i+window),time.column]
        y=data[i:(i+window),data.column]  
        lmodel=lm(y~x)
        adj_r_sqr[i+floor(window/2)-1),which(window_vekt==window)]=summary(lmodel)$adj.r.squared}
```

But this will not account for the varying time intervals.

What I would need is a tweak that screens the data frame based on the first column and subsets it in a rolling was so that the subset covers the chosen window and gives an NA if the number of row in that window is < 5.
An additional question could be to subset the data, but not in a rolling, rather in a spliced way again using the time variable.

Previously I managed to extract not only adj. r2, but p-values and other  and slopes as well using:

```
RMSE=sqrt(mean((summary(lmodel)$residuals)^2))
p_val_y=summary(lmodel)$coefficients[2,4]
p_val_intercept=summary(lmodel)$coefficients[1,4]
slope=coeff[i+summary(lmodel)$coefficients[2,1]
```

but with the old windowing, unfortunately I cannot implement these in the query suggested by @Uwe , because of my incompetence.

A test data set can be found on the link below:
[test_data.csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18GjMIaLHUc0ngw2OY4ZVZ71YBl66HWVl/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: What is the definition of `window_vekt`, please?

Comment: @Uwe It should have been just window. The fact is that I ran it with multiple window options and determined a vector (window_vect) to do so, but in the present example it is unnecessary. I can "upscale" it to run like that afterwards - hopefully. :)

Comment: @Uwe I have added the test data with which the code unfortunately fails and added a couple of additional comments. Thank you for your time!

Comment: The file [test_data.csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18GjMIaLHUc0ngw2OY4ZVZ71YBl66HWVl/view?usp=sharing) does not contain columns headers. This worked for me: `dat <- data.table::fread("testadat.csv", col.names = c("time", "var1", "var2"))`

Comment: @Uwe Sorry, wrong file, it does not work with this one  [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1myFD19Yp1m83FjT4W_Iup-kdLNbZX1z8) , which is the extended version of what I recently uploaded. It gives the error `Error in lsumm$coefficients[2, 4] : subscript out of bounds`

Comment: The error messages is caused by a group which contains only one data point. In this case `lsumm$coefficients` consists only of one row. I have updated my code to catch this situation.

Comment: anybody have a dplyr solution? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Rolling window

This can be solved by *aggregating in a non-equi join* which aggregates a varying number of rows which cover a given time period.

```
library(data.table)
# define parameters
time_1 <- -10
time_2 <- 10
n_min <- 5L
# create helper columns
setDT(dat)[, `:=`(join = time, start = time + time_1, end = time + time_2)][
  # non-equi join and aggregate 
  dat, on = .(join >= start, join <= end), by = .EACHI, {
    lmodel <- lm(var1 ~ time)
    lsumm <- summary(lmodel)
    .(time = i.time, 
      N = .N, 
      adj_r_sqr = lsumm$adj.r.squared,
      RMSE = sqrt(mean(lsumm$residuals^2)),
      p_val_y = if (.N > 1) lsumm$coefficients[2,4] else NA_real_,
      p_val_intercept = lsumm$coefficients[1,4],
      slope = coef(lmodel)[2]
    )
  }]
```

> ```
>        join    join    time  N     adj_r_sqr       RMSE     p_val_y p_val_intercept         slope
>  1: 5252.00 5272.00 5262.00  9 -1.412484e-01 0.06749996 0.923658051      0.76541424  8.050483e-04
>  2: 5253.20 5273.20 5263.20  9 -1.412484e-01 0.06749996 0.923658051      0.76541424  8.050483e-04
>  3: 5254.40 5274.40 5264.40 10 -1.248329e-01 0.06411770 0.973340896      0.77035143  2.202740e-04
>  4: 5255.60 5275.60 5265.60 11 -5.914522e-02 0.06631161 0.523022100      0.72831553 -3.713582e-03
>  5: 5256.80 5276.80 5266.80 12 -8.934954e-02 0.06570860 0.760946792      0.96376799 -1.488205e-03
>  6: 5258.00 5278.00 5268.00 13 -8.696209e-02 0.06341811 0.845238030      0.82437256 -7.998616e-04
>  7: 5259.20 5279.20 5269.20 14 -8.098718e-02 0.06260179 0.874476744      0.52663574  5.619086e-04
>  8: 5260.46 5280.46 5270.46 15 -6.931305e-02 0.06060738 0.765814583      0.39825585  9.125789e-04
>  9: 5261.84 5281.84 5271.84 16 -5.793624e-02 0.05873142 0.679041724      0.29974544  1.102731e-03
> 10: 5263.22 5283.22 5273.22 15 -6.443192e-02 0.06113970 0.702430340      0.34981142  1.151509e-03
> 11: 5264.60 5284.60 5274.60 15 -7.684134e-02 0.06444578 0.975417917      0.56686522  9.651049e-05
> 12: 5265.98 5285.98 5275.98 15  1.462585e-01 0.04608930 0.088169168      0.30888780 -4.011513e-03
> 13: 5267.36 5287.36 5277.36 15  1.964299e-02 0.04086278 0.278246773      0.81455430 -2.166657e-03
> 14: 5268.74 5288.74 5278.74 15  6.215962e-02 0.04008533 0.188319558      0.64301698 -2.594692e-03
> 15: 5270.12 5290.12 5280.12 15  4.288832e-02 0.04025402 0.224394742      0.72203401 -2.388716e-03
> 16: 5271.50 5291.50 5281.50 15  1.512386e-01 0.04851035 0.084258193      0.28641439 -4.218427e-03
> 17: 5272.88 5292.88 5282.88 14  1.381176e-01 0.05002305 0.104568029      0.29409267 -4.558051e-03
> 18: 5274.26 5294.26 5284.26 13  1.327825e-01 0.05157048 0.120223456      0.28797520 -5.072464e-03
> 19: 5275.64 5295.64 5285.64 13  3.596767e-01 0.04138389 0.017834204      0.06667444 -6.361901e-03
> 20: 5277.02 5297.02 5287.02 12  2.873660e-01 0.04305408 0.041945918      0.12120605 -6.247512e-03
> 21: 5278.40 5298.40 5288.40 12  5.028991e-01 0.05961926 0.005895787      0.01376478 -1.191625e-02
> 22: 5279.78 5299.78 5289.78 11  4.293597e-01 0.06222915 0.017042382      0.03427994 -1.172318e-02
> 23: 5281.16 5301.16 5291.16 11  2.515343e-01 0.06779510 0.066374606      0.13205602 -8.296797e-03
> 24: 5284.72 5304.72 5294.72  9 -1.061158e-01 0.08743787 0.644376920      0.85394202 -2.841506e-03
> 25: 5287.30 5307.30 5297.30  8 -1.646716e-01 0.09175885 0.922552618      0.87761939 -6.640669e-04
> 26: 5289.88 5309.88 5299.88  7  1.448103e-02 0.08454602 0.344665870      0.25432610  7.335472e-03
> 27: 5292.46 5312.46 5302.46  7 -7.071101e-02 0.08530518 0.472291173      0.35934829  5.744740e-03
> 28: 5295.04 5315.04 5305.04  7  1.737202e-01 0.07307195 0.192955618      0.13615980  9.523810e-03
> 29: 5297.62 5317.62 5307.62  7 -8.646937e-02 0.03513349 0.502173104      0.25578453  2.200997e-03
> 30: 5300.20 5320.20 5310.20  7 -1.900736e-01 0.03206618 0.846235515      0.69966581 -5.675526e-04
> 31: 5302.78 5322.78 5312.78  7  5.536354e-05 0.05732965 0.363144502      0.54063521 -4.969546e-03
> 32: 5305.36 5325.36 5315.36  7  5.335182e-02 0.05578091 0.299620417      0.45814873 -5.592470e-03
> 33: 5307.94 5327.94 5317.94  7 -1.657721e-01 0.06294568 0.717357983      0.94666422 -2.090255e-03
> 34: 5310.52 5330.52 5320.52  7 -6.028327e-02 0.06414699 0.453853207      0.63535624 -4.512735e-03
> 35: 5313.10 5333.10 5323.10  7  8.740895e-02 0.06389452 0.264987111      0.38753689 -6.949059e-03
> 36: 5315.68 5335.68 5325.68  7 -1.197917e-01 0.05898249 0.575617471      0.80276014 -3.059247e-03
> 37: 5318.26 5338.26 5328.26  7 -1.150258e-01 0.05925244 0.564069556      0.78843841 -3.169989e-03
> 38: 5320.84 5340.84 5330.84  7 -5.959161e-02 0.05513800 0.452664410      0.66756091 -3.889812e-03
> 39: 5323.42 5343.42 5333.42  7 -1.914314e-01 0.05727449 0.857057704      0.88289558 -9.413068e-04
> 40: 5326.00 5346.00 5336.00  7  1.980666e-01 0.03842399 0.175981115      0.09097818  5.246401e-03
> 41: 5328.58 5348.58 5338.58  7  2.435057e-01 0.03768830 0.147555108      0.07564568  5.592470e-03
> 42: 5331.16 5351.16 5341.16  7  1.506886e-01 0.03812754 0.210258699      0.10821693  4.748062e-03
> 43: 5333.74 5353.74 5343.74  7 -8.457396e-02 0.04203885 0.498438355      0.28478388  2.657807e-03
> 44: 5336.32 5356.32 5346.32  7 -7.010584e-02 0.04407872 0.471193766      0.27563851  2.976190e-03
> 45: 5338.90 5358.90 5348.90  7  3.356662e-01 0.03913660 0.100918300      0.05396996  6.810631e-03
> 46: 5341.48 5361.48 5351.48  7  5.571886e-01 0.03769020 0.032860686      0.01839957  9.551495e-03
> 47: 5344.06 5364.06 5354.06  7  5.543731e-01 0.03777052 0.033425890      0.01873703  9.523810e-03
> 48: 5346.64 5366.64 5356.64  7  6.568462e-01 0.04090850 0.016679391      0.01024635  1.252769e-02
> 49: 5349.22 5369.22 5359.22  7  4.263635e-01 0.04784925 0.066663521      0.04074626  9.689922e-03
> 50: 5351.80 5371.80 5361.80  7  2.805982e-01 0.03460683 0.127153338      0.06281590  5.481728e-03
> 51: 5354.38 5374.38 5364.38  7  3.716517e-01 0.03324983 0.086098144      0.04219813  6.146179e-03
> 52: 5356.96 5376.96 5366.96  7  1.502772e-01 0.03293035 0.210579418      0.09951647  4.097453e-03
> 53: 5359.54 5379.54 5369.54  7  3.375742e-01 0.03655294 0.100088760      0.05199627  6.381506e-03
> 54: 5362.12 5382.12 5372.12  7 -1.007327e-01 0.03472663 0.531670980      0.27614749  2.021041e-03
> 55: 5364.70 5384.70 5374.70  7  5.143262e-01 0.04270061 0.042184448      0.02514076  1.003599e-02
> 56: 5367.28 5387.28 5377.28  7  1.180375e-01 0.05043403 0.237081066      0.14603312  5.869324e-03
> 57: 5369.86 5389.86 5379.86  7  3.526957e-01 0.05256444 0.093690478      0.05958580  9.413068e-03
> 58: 5372.44 5392.44 5382.44  7 -1.143248e-01 0.06697669 0.562404900      0.40786204  3.599114e-03
> 59: 5375.02 5395.02 5385.02  7 -1.380467e-01 0.06582006 0.624143540      0.45527492  2.976190e-03
> 60: 5377.60 5397.60 5387.60  7 -1.437437e-01 0.08277209 0.640981907      0.80007275 -3.557586e-03
> 61: 5380.18 5400.18 5390.18  7  6.865351e-02 0.07101868 0.283553003      0.39287969 -7.392027e-03
> 62: 5382.76 5402.76 5392.76  7 -1.557062e-01 0.06968790 0.679826634      0.87463729 -2.643965e-03
> 63: 5385.34 5405.34 5395.34  7 -5.672857e-02 0.06614976 0.447786680      0.61411355 -4.720377e-03
> 64: 5387.92 5407.92 5397.92  7 -1.978539e-01 0.05568786 0.928270615      0.68172236  4.568106e-04
> 65: 5390.50 5410.50 5400.50  7 -1.682576e-01 0.05373328 0.727529980      0.98771567 -1.716501e-03
> 66: 5393.08 5413.08 5403.08  7  3.659413e-01 0.03870980 0.088336383      0.04816083  7.087486e-03
> 67: 5395.66 5415.66 5405.66  7 -5.189744e-02 0.02893483 0.439709327      0.19602199  2.104097e-03
> 68: 5398.24 5418.24 5408.24  7  6.657153e-02 0.02820253 0.285688876      0.12137978  2.920819e-03
> 69: 5400.82 5420.82 5410.82  7 -3.417829e-02 0.02978965 0.411610972      0.18697576  2.311739e-03
> 70: 5403.40 5423.40 5413.40  6 -1.689106e-01 0.03205016 0.626213128      0.38442443  1.915836e-03
> 71: 5405.98 5425.98 5415.98  5 -3.324952e-01 0.03383253 0.968080223      0.75067625  2.325581e-04
> 72: 5408.56 5428.56 5418.56  4  4.196229e-01 0.01811905 0.217004528      0.29310481 -7.906977e-03
>        join    join    time  N     adj_r_sqr       RMSE     p_val_y p_val_intercept         slope
> ```

---

**EDIT:** The OP has posted the [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1myFD19Yp1m83FjT4W_Iup-kdLNbZX1z8) to another sample dataset which ran into an error. The reason is that some group sizes are too small consisting of only one data point so that the linear model has no slope.

The updated version of the code catches this situation and prevents an out-of-bounds error.

---

The first two columns show the range of years which is covered; they can be removed if no longer needed .

`N` is the number of rows included in the computation of `lm()`. The OP has requested to return `NA` if `N < 5`.  This also can be done afterwards.

```
# define parameters
time_1 <- -10
time_2 <- 10
n_min <- 5L
# coerce to data.table
result <- setDT(dat)[
  # create helper columns
  , `:=`(join = time, start = time + time_1, end = time + time_2)][
    # non-equi join and aggregate each interval 
    dat, on = .(join >= start, join <= end), by = .EACHI, {
      # do computations within interval
      lmodel <- lm(var1 ~ time)
      lsumm <- summary(lmodel)
      # create list of results, finally
      .(time = i.time, 
        N = .N, 
        adj_r_sqr = lsumm$adj.r.squared,
        RMSE = sqrt(mean(lsumm$residuals^2)),
        p_val_y = if (.N > 1) lsumm$coefficients[2,4] else NA_real_,
        p_val_intercept = lsumm$coefficients[1,4],
        slope = coef(lmodel)[2]
      )
    }]
# clean-up result
computed_cols <- setdiff(names(result), c(names(dat), "N"))
result[
  # remove join columns
  , -(1:2)][
    # put NA if too few data points
    N < n_min, (computed_cols) := NA][]
```

> ```
>        time  N     adj_r_sqr       RMSE     p_val_y p_val_intercept         slope
>  1: 5262.00  9 -1.412484e-01 0.06749996 0.923658051      0.76541424  8.050483e-04
>  2: 5263.20  9 -1.412484e-01 0.06749996 0.923658051      0.76541424  8.050483e-04
>  3: 5264.40 10 -1.248329e-01 0.06411770 0.973340896      0.77035143  2.202740e-04
>     ...
> 70: 5413.40  6 -1.689106e-01 0.03205016 0.626213128      0.38442443  1.915836e-03
> 71: 5415.98  5 -3.324952e-01 0.03383253 0.968080223      0.75067625  2.325581e-04
> 72: 5418.56  4            NA         NA          NA              NA            NA
>        time  N     adj_r_sqr       RMSE     p_val_y p_val_intercept         slope
> ```

#### Splitting by fixed intervals

The OP has also asked

> An additional question could be to subset the data, but not in a
>   rolling, rather in a spliced way again using the time variable.

```
# define parameters
n_min <- 5L
t_len <- 20
# create "pretty" breaks 
breaks <- setDT(dat)[, seq(floor(min(time)/t_len)*t_len, max(time) + t_len, t_len)]
dat[, {
  lmodel <- lm(var1 ~ time)
  lsumm <- summary(lmodel)
  .(t_min = min(time),
    t_max = max(time),
    N = .N, 
    adj_r_sqr = lsumm$adj.r.squared,
    RMSE = sqrt(mean(lsumm$residuals^2)),
    p_val_y = if (.N > 1) lsumm$coefficients[2,4] else NA_real_,
    p_val_intercept = lsumm$coefficients[1,4],
    slope = coef(lmodel)[2]
  )
}, by = .(cut(time, breaks))]
```

> ```
>                    cut   t_min   t_max  N   adj_r_sqr       RMSE    p_val_y p_val_intercept         slope
> 1: (5.26e+03,5.28e+03] 5262.00 5278.74 14 -0.08098718 0.06260179 0.87447674      0.52663574  0.0005619086
> 2:  (5.28e+03,5.3e+03] 5280.12 5299.88 12  0.33144858 0.06512008 0.02934449      0.06866916 -0.0087040163
> 3:  (5.3e+03,5.32e+03] 5302.46 5317.94  7 -0.19007362 0.03206618 0.84623551      0.69966581 -0.0005675526
> 4: (5.32e+03,5.34e+03] 5320.52 5338.58  8 -0.16348201 0.06360759 0.90221583      0.62280945  0.0005629384
> 5: (5.34e+03,5.36e+03] 5341.16 5359.22  8  0.54042068 0.03778046 0.02285248      0.01024298  0.0079272794
> 6: (5.36e+03,5.38e+03] 5361.80 5379.86  8  0.20369592 0.03803705 0.14585425      0.06090703  0.0043881506
> 7:  (5.38e+03,5.4e+03] 5382.44 5397.92  7  0.06865351 0.07101868 0.28355300      0.39287969 -0.0073920266
> 8:  (5.4e+03,5.42e+03] 5400.50 5418.56  8 -0.04065894 0.02837687 0.42672518      0.14267960  0.0016703581
> ```

Comment: I tired to extend it to  extract not only adj r2, but the slope and the p-values as well, but the way your extraction is written is unfamiliar for me. Previously I referred to these with a code I added to the original post. If you could refer me to a place where I can find the logic of the querying, or just extend it with a line that I could replicate would be super useful.

Is it by the way possible to put this in a for cycle and run it with multiple windows, because at the moment I cannot adjust the time window with a variable outside of the function e.g. time_1=-10 ; time_2=10.

Comment: Thank very much! Is it possible to not just roll but slice the data in a similar manner...?

Comment: The helper columns are added, but afterwards both codes give an error:
Error in lsumm$coefficients[2, 4] : subscript out of bounds

However, if I take the 
#   p_val_y = lsumm$coefficients[2,4], 
or other similar lines out it gives:

Error in `[.data.table`(setDT(dat)[, `:=`(join = time, start = time +  : 
  LHS of := appears to be column positions but are outside [1,ncol] range. New columns can only be added by name.

I tried the script with other data as well, and it gave the same error, please find a set attached to the question in an hour.

Comment: I would happily try to help solve the problem if you could add comments the code, describing which line refers to what task, (obliously the important ones) so I could read about it, since the next step would be to not just do a linear model to the segments, but anything else (plot a histogram, calculate an average or a breakpoint analysis) and extract the results into a matrix.

Comment: With another testdata [https://drive.google.com/open?id=1lXPANkQgFp3y3AwyHuOyMbN0W0-5V8NH] the last cleaning lines did not remove all the the values corresponding to N<5, so I looked up one of your answers to another question and based on that I would suggest `setDT(result)[N<n_min,(computed_cols) := NA][]
result=result[,-1:-2]` .

Comment: @IstvanGaborHatvani Please, can you doublecheck the link? It returns _Error 404 - File not found_.

Comment: I do not know why the link did not work, here it is again [I do not know why the link did not work, here it is again [https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lXPANkQgFp3y3AwyHuOyMbN0W0-5V8NH/view?usp=sharing]

Comment: The link in the prvious comment did not work because an "]" was included in the Google Drive id.  With the correct link, the data loaded well and my scripts did run without any error message and gave the expected result.

Comment: in that case the fault was somewhere in my code, but anyhow it works with both of your codes, thank you very much! :)